# How do I insert text into textbox from line in file in multiple textboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, text-files

I am trying to do something but I haven't found anything on google since I don't know how to word it to get the right results.

I have a Form with 9 TextBox controls, and a PlainText file with 9 lines of text.

I want to click a button which will then add the first line of text from the text file into the first TextBox, then the second line into the second textbox, and so on... Can anybody please provide any advice on how to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("yourFileName.txt"))
{
    textBox1.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox2.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox3.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox4.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox5.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox6.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox7.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox8.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox9.Text = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

***edit:*** changed solution to use `File.OpenText` instead of `FileStream`

Comment: perfect - thank you so much :) I'd completely forgotten all about StreamReader it's been so long since i've used it I always use File.ReadAllText nowadays lol

Comment: `File.OpenText` would be simpler, but indeed.

Comment: thank you Marc G. I haven't used OpenText before I will try it out :)